# MYSQL: How to Insert Multiple row by parameter values in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I googled and I found solution for inserting multiple rows like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `usAddCostumeSet` 
    (argUserID BIGINT, argStarOID INT, argAcc1 INT, argAcc2 INT, 
     argBody INT, argHead INT, argNow DateTime)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO COSTUME (UserID, StarOID, CostumeOID, CostumeTID, IsNewMark, CreateDate, FavDate) 
    VALUES (argUserID, argStarOID, argAcc1, argAcc1, true, argNow, null),
           (argUserID, argStarOID, argAcc2, argAcc2, true, argNow, null),
           (argUserID, argStarOID, argBody, argBody, true, argNow, null),
           (argUserID, argStarOID, argHead, argHead, true, argNow, null);

END
```

and I wish make it something like below

```
INSERT INTO COSTUME (UserID, StarOID, CostumeOID, CostumeTID, IsNewMark, CreateDate, FavDate)  
VALUES 
     if argAcc1 is not Zero (argUserID, argStarOID, argAcc1, argAcc1, true, argNow, null),
     if argAcc2 is not Zero (argUserID, argStarOID, argAcc2, argAcc2, true, argNow, null),
     if argBody is not Zero (argUserID, argStarOID, argBody, argBody, true, argNow, null),
     if argHead is not Zero (argUserID, argStarOID, argHead, argHead, true, argNow, null);

END
```

Is there a neat solution?

Comment: You want to insert 1 row or up to 4 rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO COSTUME (UserID, StarOID, CostumeOID, 
                     CostumeTID, IsNewMark, CreateDate, FavDate) 
SELECT argUserID, argStarOID, 
  CASE WHEN argAcc1 <> 0 THEN argAcc1
       WHEN argAcc2 <> 0 THEN argAcc2
       WHEN argBody <> 0 THEN argBody
       WHEN argHead <> 0 THEN argHead
  END,
  CASE WHEN argAcc1 <> 0 THEN argAcc1
       WHEN argAcc2 <> 0 THEN argAcc2
       WHEN argBody <> 0 THEN argBody
       WHEN argHead <> 0 THEN argHead
  END,
  true, argNow, null
```

Answer (score 0):

for a while thinking

i realize one solution. using Union all

i don't know how to measure performance or danger anyway here is the code.

```
INSERT INTO COSTUME SELECT argUserID, argStarOID, tempTbl.idx, tempTbl.idx, true, argNow, null FROM (SELECT argAcc1 as idx UNION ALL
SELECT argAcc2 UNION ALL
SELECT argHair UNION ALL
SELECt argBody) as tempTbl WHERE tempTbl.idx != 0;
```

but after all i decide use Transaction and multiple IF statement.....

any advice will be granted... thanks